# Как экранировать слова в которых есть дефис java

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения, экранирование

Сейчас пытаюсь экранировать так, но  остается "-то"

```
String result2 = result1.replaceAll("\\кто-то"," ");
```

Если экранировать так,то остается  "то"

```
String result2 = result1.replaceAll("\\-|\\кто-то"," ");
```

Так экранировать так не вариант, потому что удаляются частицы "то" из других слов

```
String result2 = result1.replaceAll("\\-|\\кто-то|\\то"," ");
```

Требуется удалить(заменить на пробел) слова "кто-то", "кто-либо" и тому подобные из имеющейся строки.

Comment: Ни `к`, ни `-` не надо экранировать.

Comment: имею ввиду также "кто-нибудь", какие-либо" и т.д. Можно придумать множество вариантов подобных местоимений. Ваш ответ помог, просто пропишу побольше вариантов. Например result2 = result.replaceAll("\\bкто-(?:то|либо|нибудь)\\b|\\bкакой-(?:то|либо|нибудь)\\b|\\bчто-(?:то|либо|нибудь)\\b|\\bкак-(?:то|либо|нибудь)\\b ", " ");

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы можете использовать

```
(?U)\bкто-(?:то|либо)\b
```

См. [пример работы регулярного выражения](https://regex101.com/r/t38L1X/1/).

**Подробности**

- `(?U)` - для старых версий Java этот флаг необходим, чтобы граница слова `\b` правильно работала с Юникодом
- `\b` - граница слова
- `кто-` - подстрока `кто-`
- `(?:то|либо)` - либо `то`, либо `либо`
- `\b` - граница слова

См. [пример кода на Java](https://ideone.com/1A9beu):

```
String text = "Требуется заменить на пробел слова \"кто-то\", \"кто-либо\" и тому подобные из имеющейся строки.";
System.out.println(text.replaceAll("(?U)\\bкто-(?:то|либо)\\b", " "));
// => Требуется заменить на пробел слова " ", " " и тому подобные из имеющейся строки.
```

Можно далее расширить шаблон до, например,

```
(?Ui)\b(?:кто|как\p{L}*)-(?:то|либо|нибудь)\b
```

См. [пример работы этого регулярного выражения](https://regex101.com/r/t38L1X/2/). Тут `\p{L}*` находит 0 и более любых букв, а `(?i)` обеспечивает регистронезависимый поиск.